# Rolling window function in Google Cloud monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring, uptime-monitoring

I am setting up an uptime check in Google cloud monitoring. When I add the check I also create an alert policy. Furthermore I set my check to global which means it will check from 6 different locations and I set the check frequency.

The alerting policy that was created (in cloud console when I created uptime check) has a rolling window set to 20 minutes and Rolling window function set to "next older".

I am trying to understand this

1. Rolling window 20 min: Does that mean I will get one alert every 20 min or what is affected by this 20 minute window?
2. next older: Does this mean it somehow uses data from the previous 20 minute slot? I don't understand this one.

Finally under Configure trigger there is also

Retest window: Does it do any retest in that period or does it just hold off on alerting for that amount of time to confirm it did not resolve?

Answer (score 1):

This official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/concepts-indepth#duration) provides two different examples that describe when the condition is met. The following content is taken from official docs

**Rolling window:**

When using a rolling time window (or real time window), the metrics are calculated or analyzed for a particular alignment period, for example if you consider an alignment period of five minutes, at 1:00 PM, the alignment period contains the samples received between 12:55 PM and 1:00 PM. At 1:01 PM, the alignment period slides one minute and contains the samples received between 12:56 PM and 1:01 PM.

[image]

The first graph illustrates a combined case with an alignment period set to 5 minutes and a duration window of 3 minutes. The example illustrates when the aligned value exceeds the threshold and when the condition is met.

**Retest window:**

Even though the aligned value is greater than the threshold at time start + 2 minutes, the condition doesn't trigger until the aligned value is greater than the threshold for three minutes. That event occurs at time start + 5 minutes.

[image]

**Example**:

> This alerting policy contains one metric-threshold condition that
> specifies a five-minute duration window.
>
> Opening an incident and sending email to your support team is possible
> only  if the HTTP response latency is greater than two seconds, and if
> the latency continues to be above the criteria for five minutes.
>
> 1.Less than two seconds is HTTP latency
>
> 2.HTTP latency exceeds two seconds during the following three minutes.
>
> 3.The condition resets the duration window when the latency in the subsequent measurement is less than two seconds.
>
> 4.The condition is met when HTTP latency exceeds two seconds for the following five minutes.
>
> **Note**:Set the duration window to be long enough to minimize false positives, but short enough to ensure that incidents are opened in a
> timely manner.
>
> **Next older**: To retain only the most recent sample within an alignment period, use the next older aligner. This aligner is commonly
> used with uptime checks and is a good choice when you only care about
> the most recent value. This aligner is valid only for gauge metrics.

Comment: My remaining question is. If I have an uptime check that is set to "global" meaning it tests from 6 hosts and set it to 5 min testinterval. If I then have the aligner set to 10 min and next older. It means 2 checks (10 hosts in total) will be done in 10 min. What will be included when I use next older?

Comment: Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-quota-metrics#:~:text=The%20rolling%20window%20function%20is,value%20of%20this%20GAUGE%20metric.&text=Select%20sum%20.,individual%20time%20series%20is%20comb) for more information about Next older

Comment: I have, I still don't get it fully. I read all about this all in docs before asking the question.